# FullCalendar open bootstrap modal on eventClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap fullcalendar, when I click on an empty day, the modal which allows to save the events is displayed well, but when I click on an event to modify it, the modal which allows to modify the event, does't display.

I have a bootstrap fullcalendar, when I click on an empty day, the modal which allows to save the events is displayed well, but when I click on an event to modify it, the modal which allows to modify the event, does't display.

I don't know where the problem comes from
this is my code :

```
      

<div  class="modal fade" id="PrestUpt" role="dialog" class="modal fade task-modal-single in" tabindex="-1"  aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" >
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content data">
                        <div id="jalil" ></div>
                            
                               
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


<script>
   
  $(document).ready(function() {
     // jQuery("#PrestUpt").modal('show');
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        locale: 'fr',
        plugins: [ 'bootstrap', 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
        firstDay: 1,
    editable:true,
    header:{
        left:'prev,next today',
        center:'title',
        right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: 'event_load_new.php',
    selectable:true,
    selectHelper:true,
select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            //do something when space selected
            //Show 'add event' modal
            // var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD");
            document.getElementById('start').value = start;
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
        },
    editable:true,
    eventResize:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"event_update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function(){
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert("Mise à jour de l'événement");
      }
     })
    },
    
    eventClick: function(info) {
        var idpr = info.event.id;
    
        alert(idpr);
        // datepr = datepr.substr(6, 4)+ '' +datepr.substr(3, 2)+ '' +datepr.substr(0, 2);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'moadal_gool.php', //Here you will fetch records 
           data :  'idp='+idpr, //Pass $id
            success : function(data){
            $('#jalil').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
            jQuery("#PrestUpt").modal('show');
            }
        });
            
    },

    eventDrop:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"event_update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function()
      {
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert("Événement mis à jour");
      }
     });
    },

    

   });
  });
   
  </script>
```

Comment: Instead of repeating yourself pointlessly in the question text, explain what debugging you've done so far. Maybe your ajax call is failing, for example? Have you used your browser tools to investigate? We can't run that code to see what would happen so you need to check it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it...

```
eventClick: this.openModal.bind(this)

//then create a function openModal()
openModal(args:any){
    jQuery("#PrestUpt").modal("show");
    ...
}
```

Comment: That will show the modal just fine. But it will work only once :( The content of the modal will never get new contents without a page refresh

Comment: You can call the method that fetches the modal content inside ```openModal```

Comment: openModal is that your own custom function?

Comment: Yes that's my own custom function

Comment: and does that invoke the show/shown and hide/hidden BS modal events?

Comment: No, you'll have to implement that by yourself

Comment: Still the same problem then. The modal doesn't fire off any events once opened so you can't replace the content :(

Comment: Kindly share your code